# Show Hidden Objects Upon Clicking Button (PHP with javaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick, hidden

How do I display the hidden text field through javaScript by using PHP counter. I have this code in HTML incorporated with PHP:

```
   <?php if(isset($prior)): foreach($prior as $row): ?>
   <tr>
         <td> <?php echo $row->priority?> </td>
         <td> <?php echo $row->priority_time?> </td>
         <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>
              <input  type="text" id="" name="<?php echo $row->priority_id?>" hidden/>
         </td>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach;?>
   <?php else:?>
         <p>Request Service not available</p>
   <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first give your hidden input an id, then inside a function where you want to remove the hidden class:

`var myButtonClasses = document.getElementById("theGivenId").classList;
myButtonClasses.remove("hidden");`

source: [classlist](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP loop:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="showField(<?php echo $row->priority_id; ?>)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Add a JS function to the page:

```
function showField(name) {
  var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + name + '"]');
  el.setAttribute('hidden', false);
}
```

Comment: How do you add a php code in the javaScript though?

Comment: You are not adding PHP code to JS. You are adding a JS function, called `showField` to the page and using PHP to add the `name` parameter to the function called inside the `onclick` of the `button`.

Answer (score 0):

use css as hidden for input , allow button click to call a javascript function in which you may do your other task along with 
 document.getElementById("theGivenId").style.visibility = "visible";